# How to convert Germany type F (CEE 7/4) welder device to US NEMA Type 60-20P?

Tags: voltage, ac

I am considering buying a Stahlwerk welder which is (Germany) type F (CEE 7/4) 230V 50Hz to use in the US 240V 60Hz NEMA type 20A 6-20P. The welder's specifications are +/- 15% so it seems like it would be fine electrically. What would be the proper wiring conversion or would there be polarity issues?

Comment: How do you know it can work with 60 Hz?

Comment: yes you can i have a German one in the Netherlands where the ac is 240/260 ac

Comment: What welder? Inverter based one?

Comment: The welder brand is Stahlwerk. 
It is inverter based.
The manufacturer states it will work 50/60hz @230V +/- 15%

Answer (score 0):

> would there be polarity issues?

In general European portable appliances are not sensitive to polarity for two reasons.

1. Many countries in Europe use non-polarised plugs. In such countries there is a 50% chance that the nominally neutral wire of the appliance will be connected to phase and vice-versa.
2. While the 230/400 system is the most common in Europe, it's not the only system. Some parts of Europe do have 230V supplies where neither pin is neutral.

As a result of this it is unlikely you will have polarity related issues when connecting a European appliance to an American 240V supply.

Frequency is potentially more of a problem though, particularly with stuff involving motors.

> What would be the proper wiring conversion

Brown to one hot, blue to the other hot, green/yellow to ground.

Comment: Thank you Peter.